# Access to Oracle XmlType column through ODBC with data over 4K

Tags: oracle, odbc, xmltype

Our legacy C++ ODBC application recently added support for XML data columns (data type xml in MS SQL Server, XmlType in Oracle). We used

```
SQLBindParameter( hStmt, i, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, ... )
```

for our insert/update queries, and

```
SQLBindCol( hStmt, i, SQL_C_CHAR, ... )
```

for our selects. While the XML data remained small, this worked fine on both DBMS. MS SQL Server also handles larger XML data without issues, on Oracle we ran into the 4K limit for string literals though.

We realize that we can use CLOB columns instead in Oracle (and varchar(max) on MS SQL) to store larger XML data bound with SQL_LONGVARCHAR. However, we can only change the database schema in our next major version.

Is there any way to get Oracle to work with data over 4K characters through ODBC while keeping the column as XmlType?

I've found various workarounds in PL/SQL, but nothing that applies to ODBC. Attempting to use PL/SQL stored procedures that take CLOB in parameters as helpers only resulted in the same

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

error message that we also get when directly attempting to bind the column.

Comment: Which ODBC driver do you use? The driver from Microsoft or from Oracle?

Comment: We are using Oracle's driver, version 12.01.00.02.